# Does CSS content-visibility improve image decode times?

Tags: css, image, performance-testing, web-performance

Does the CSS `content-visibility` property improve image decode times in browsers like Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

At least from the Chrome browser perspective, it is not believed that the use of `content-visibility:auto` can offer meaningful savings on image decode.

`content-visibility` allows us to now style of layout things when they are offscreen, offering a rendering benefit. However, when it comes to image decodes, there are two primary things to keep in mind: is the image painted? and are we rasterizing content that uses this image?

For the first of these points, it is true that we do not paint the image content for `content-visibility` affected images, so there may be some small savings here. At raster time however, we only decode images which happen to be needed for rasterization. We only reserve a small area around the viewport. This means that it is pretty unlikely we could have decoded an even somewhat distant offscreen image, with or without content-visibility set.

Note: For paints, there could be situations where browsers decode an image (like determining if we should invert it for dark theme). However, these situations are quite rare as doing decodes at paint time is something we aim to avoid.